# Dining philosophers implementation

Tags: java

I'm just wondering if this all there is to solving the dining philosophers problem in java?

```
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class MainClass {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Lock forks[] = new ReentrantLock[5];

    for(int i = 0; i<5; i++){
        forks[i] = new ReentrantLock(); 
    }

    Thread p1 = new Thread(new Philosopher(forks[4], forks[0], "first"));
    Thread p2 = new Thread(new Philosopher(forks[0], forks[1], "second"));
    Thread p3 = new Thread(new Philosopher(forks[1], forks[2], "third"));
    Thread p4 = new Thread(new Philosopher(forks[2], forks[3], "fourth"));
    Thread p5 = new Thread(new Philosopher(forks[3], forks[4], "fifth"));

    p1.start();
    p2.start();
    p3.start();
    p4.start();
    p5.start(); 
  }
}
```

and my philosopher class:

```
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class Philosopher implements Runnable {

Lock leftFork = new ReentrantLock();
Lock rightFork = new ReentrantLock();
String name; 

public Philosopher(Lock leftFork, Lock rightFork, String name) {
    this.leftFork = leftFork;
    this.rightFork = rightFork;
    this.name = name; 
}

@Override
public void run() {

    while(true){
    think(name);
    eat(leftFork, rightFork, name); 
    }
}

private void eat(Lock leftFork, Lock rightFork, String name){
    leftFork.lock();
    rightFork.lock(); 

    System.out.println(name + " eating...");

    try {
        Thread.sleep(3000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    finally{
        leftFork.unlock();
        rightFork.unlock(); 
        System.out.println(name + " done eating...");
    }
}

private void think(String name){
    System.out.println(name + " thinking...");

    try {
        Thread.sleep(100);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}

}
```

It feels like there should be more..code. But i've run the program and it does what the problem is asking me to solve. Only two philosophers are eating at any one time, other wise they are thinking.

Do i have this right?

Comment: This should be migrated to `codereview.stackexchange.com`.

Answer (score 2):

No, this code is not safe from deadlock.

It is possible for all 5 Philosophers to acquire their left fork; they will then all wait forever for their right fork.

To demonstrate this, insert a brief `sleep()`, or even just a `println()` between `leftFork.lock()` and `rightFork.lock()`, which should make it fail most of the time. The current code fails occasionally on my system even without provoking it with the extra delay.

Comment: weird, i tried putting the sleep and the println in between the two lock() calls, but it still works..

Comment: It may be harder to provoke the problem depending on your system. I am running it on a 6-core CPU, which might make it more obvious.

Comment: can you give me some advice on how to avoid the deadlock no matter the cpu?

Comment: you could take a look at the `ReentrantLock.tryLock(timeout, unit)` method, i.e. the Philosopher gives up his one fork if he can't get the second fork within a limited time.

Comment: I just want to make sure that i am understanding the problem. It's possible that all five threads all acquire their left locks which means that none of them can get their right locks which leaves us in deadlock right?